# Process with() statement after if() condition in one line

Tags: python

This line doesn't make much sense, but I wonder why it raises a syntax error:

`x = 1; if x: with open("x.txt") as f: f.write(x)`

How can I execute `with` block after `if` statement in one line?

Comment: Why does it have to be on one line?

Comment: Because I need similar code in bash script, and wonder why it doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand. Is this a Python question, or a bash question?

Comment: bash and python have nothing in common.

Comment: wow people, why all this aggression? `x=1; if x: print x` works fine. I wonder why I can't use `with` statement w/o being put on fire

Comment: it's a syntax error, plain and simple.  see the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html).

Comment: Upvote to fight the power. But I hope you aren't actually writing this code :)

Comment: The real question is ... why does it need to be in one line in your bash script ... there's no need ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The with statement is a red herring. Even the following is syntax error:

```
>>> x = 1; if x: if x: print x
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 1; if x: if x: print x
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

See here:

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html

> A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines. Only the latter form of suite can contain nested compound statements; the following is illegal, mostly because it wouldn’t be clear to which `if` clause a following `else` clause would belong:
>
> ```
> if test1: if test2: print x
> ```

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason you need to be able to provide a single line input in your bash script.  Here is a bash script that will pass a multiline command to python

```
$ less wibble.sh
python -c "
x = 1
if x:
    if x:
        print x
"
```

And here is it running

```
$ bash wibble.sh
1
```

Comment: +1 for a demonstration that 'problem behind the problem' is a non-problem !